# How to update a list with snapshot values from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, flutter-listview

I have an application which fetches data related to videos(vedioId,description,number of views,likes) from firestore and display it in a listview using streambuilder. It also have a feature to search data. The search data is done locally in system and it works fine. But the problem happens when I try to update data when clicking like button in the list. Since the data is  fetched using streambuilder as snapshots, I uses a list to store snapshots from the stream and apply modification to that list when search happens. But I cannot update the list when clicking like button after searching. I cannot update the list of video like normal list because the values have string indeces(eg:list[index]["video"]). how can I update the list having snapshot values.

Here is the code for listview and streambuilder

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: _streamController.stream,
     
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
       
        if (!snapshot.hasData){

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());}
        else{
         
        allresults = snapshot.data!.docs;
          if(searchb00l) {

            allresultslist = snapshot.data!.docs;
           

        
          }else{
          
            allResults = resultsList;
          }ListView.builder(
            controller: _mainScroll,
            itemCount: allResults.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {List _likList =  allResults[index]["lik"];......}
```

Here is the code for searching

```
 onSearchChanged(String val){
var showResults = [];

if(val != "") {
  searchb00l = true;
  for(var titlePattern in allresults){
    var title = titlePattern['des'].toLowerCase();
    if(title.contains(val.toLowerCase())) {
      showResults.add(titlePattern);
      print(showResults.length);
    }
  }

} else {
  searchb00l = false;
 
 showResults = List.from(allresults);

}

  resultsList = showResults;
```

}

as you can see the data is displayed from the list allresults, I want to update this list after clicking like button of the list of video. But I cannot update this list using this code

```
allResults[index]["lik"]=newlikearray;
```

is there any way to update this array containing snapshot.data.docs value